# How to politely decline invitation to a work party?

Tags: professionalism, communication

My parent is very sick with covid and I have a virtual leaving drinks planned that I'd rather not attend, is there a way I can politely decline the invite?

I'm in an emotional state as it is and do not get along with all my co-workers as it is... I would rather avoid the awkwardness and leave without a fuss.

How can I politely decline without burning bridges?

Comment: Might be useful https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/139942/i-received-a-dinner-invitation-through-my-employers-email-is-it-ok-to-attend

Comment: Couldn't you just say, "Sorry, I came into contact with my parents who have covid-19 and out of an abundance of caution, I must decline the offer???" What is wrong with that? Unless you're going to work despite your parents being sick in which case you need to go home immediately.

Comment: @Dan She said "virtual drinks." I think this is like sign onto Zoom and everyone has a drink at their house. Those are awkward even when you are not worried about your family. Tammy- I hope everything works out for you and your parent.

Comment: Tammy, are you the one leaving? So you are the guest of honor as it were?

Comment: **is there a way I can politely decline the invite?** Yes. Politely decline the invite. Are you asking us how to be polite or are you asking us to tell you exactly what to say? "My apologies but I won't be able to make it" seems perfectly acceptable.

Comment: why did you plan a virtual drinks? Just cancel the whole thing due to family issues.

Answer (score 15):

Just say something along the lines of:

"Sorry, I have a family matter that I need to address and I won't be able to make it for drinks."

If you communicate this in text add a smiley or something to convey tone. People are reasonable and everyone is going through stuff right now I can't imagine this would be held against you by any reasonable person.

Edit: I missed this was for leave/resignation I have updated the answer

Comment: Hmm, never include "sorry" - it is a huge point of confusion and will just, well, confuse readers.  You're not "sorry", and you're not looking for alternatives. So, I'd say just deleted the "Sorry, "

Comment: I'm Canadian, so possible a cultural difference on this but I would include it as a nicety, especially if the event is already planned.

Comment: @PatrickKelly - As an Australian, I'd also use the word. I mean - drinks aren't planned as a punishment. They're a gesture of good-will. Not saying sorry as you refused them would for me, further cement how much we don't get along.

Comment: Also as a Canadian, I would also say "sorry" in this context.

Comment: As an American so would I.

Comment: As an alternative to "sorry", something like "thanks for your understanding" carries a similar conciliatory tone without the connotations of accepting fault.

Comment: "Sends their apologies" is the formal expression of regret for being unable to attend a meeting or event, so "Sorry" in this context seems perfectly clear (and polite) to me.